# Firebase security rules custom field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

My Firebase security rules look as follows:

```
"users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",

        // grants read access to any user who is logged in with an email and password
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'"
      }
    },
```

In addition, I have a custom `userId`, which I store in `users/$uid`. So as an example my `users/$uid` look as follows:

```
users
   /$uid
       /email: foo@bar.com
       /userId: "foobargayid123456"
```

I use this userId in other nodes, for example the node `profile_pictures` to set the dependencies:

```
profile_pictures
   /userId
       /thumbnail: "datablabla"
```

**Question**

How can I set the security rules in firebase for the node profile_pictures such that only user with id: `users/$uid/userId` can `.write` the node `profile_pictures/userId`

Comment: When a user changes their email address for an existing account, their `uid` will stay the same. Are you using `ref.changeEmail` that is documented here? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html#section-changing-passwords

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes you are right. I was assuming that it did change as this happened to me when I used a library a couple of months ago. Thanks, I have updated my question.

Comment: Are `uid` and `userId` the same values? If not, you should probably change that. It doesn't make sense to keep two different ids for the same user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
{ 
  "rules": {
    "profile_pictures": {
      "$userId": {
        ".write": "
          root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('userId').val == $userId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Really intuitive way as well.